# ClickOnce application shortcut lost image and start updating itself

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, shortcut, ico

I have an ClickOnce application, which in some case loses its icon. I mean, it doesnt disappear whole icon, but my custom icon for application and it displays default icon instead. After application loses its icon, after executing it, it automatically starts downloading and updating application, even there is no new version. Application lose its icon without making any changes or releasing an update. I don`t event have to start application to reproduce this behavior. It is happening from time to time and I dont know why. Has anybody any experience with it? I start to think that my OS WIN10 make some changes in system registry, which can effect.